# using sed commands to delete all numbers in a specific row

Tags: text, sed, replace

This might exist elsewhere but I could not find it. My goal is to delete extra numbers from a blast search to pull out sequence data while keeping the numerical sequence id. For example

Orginal:

```
>k141_100041 flag=0 multi=242.9841 len=43238
Sbjct  16375  MSEELTQNSGSNYSASSIQVLEGLEAVRKRPAMYIGDISEKGLHHLVYEVVDNSIDEALA  16196
Sbjct  16195  GYCTHIEVTINEDNSITVQDNGRGIPVDFHEKEKKSALEVVMTVLHAGGKFDKGSYKVSG  16016
Sbjct  16015  GLHGVGVSCVNALSTHMTTNVFRNGKIYQQEYECGKPLYAVKEVGTTDITGTRQTFWPDG  15836
Sbjct  15835  SIFTVTEYKYSILQARMRELAYLNKGITITLTDKRVKEEDGSYKQEKFHSEEGVKEFVRF  15656
Sbjct  15655  LNSNNTPLIDDVIYLNTEKQGIPIECAIMYNTGFRENLHSYVNNINTIEGGTHEAGFRMA  15476
Sbjct  15475  LTRVLKKYAEESKALEKAKVEISGEDFREGLIAVISVKVSEPQFEGQTKTKLGNNEVSGA  15296
Sbjct  15295  VNQAVGEALTYYLEEHPKEAKIIVDKVVLAATARVAARKARESVQRKSPMGGGGLPGKLA  15116
Sbjct  15115  DCSSRVAEECELFLVEGDSAGGSAKQGRSRQFQAILPLRGKILNVEKAMWHKAFESDDVN  14936
Sbjct  14935  NIIQALGVRFGVDGEEDSKKANIDKLRYHKVIIMTDADVDGSHIDTLIMTLFYRYMPEVI  14756
Sbjct  14755  QGGHLYIATPPLYKCSKGKISEYCYTDEARQAFIQKYGEGNEQGIHTQRYKGLGEMNPEQ  14576
Sbjct  14575  LWETTMNPETRILKQVNIENAAEADYIFSMLMGDDVGPRREFIEKNATYANIDA  14414
```

Goal:

```
>k141_112817 flag=0 multi=66.5284 len=335023
MSEELTQNSGSNYSASSIQVLEGLEAVRKRPAMYIGDISEKGLHHLVYEVVDNSIDEALA
GYCTHIEVTINEDNSITVQDNGRGIPVDFHEKEKKSALEVVMTVLHAGGKFDKGSYKVSG
GLHGVGVSCVNALSTHMTTNVFRNGKIYQQEYECGKPLYAVKEVGTTDITGTRQTFWPDG
SIFTVTEYKYSILQARMRELAYLNKGITITLTDKRVKEEDGSYKQEKFHSEEGVKEFVRF
LNSNNTPLIDDVIYLNTEKQGIPIECAIMYNTGFRENLHSYVNNINTIEGGTHEAGFRMA
LTRVLKKYAEESKALEKAKVEISGEDFREGLIAVISVKVSEPQFEGQTKTKLGNNEVSGA
VNQAVGEALTYYLEEHPKEAKIIVDKVVLAATARVAARKARESVQRKSPMGGGGLPGKLA
DCSSRVAEECELFLVEGDSAGGSAKQGRSRQFQAILPLRGKILNVEKAMWHKAFESDDVN
NIIQALGVRFGVDGEEDSKKANIDKLRYHKVIIMTDADVDGSHIDTLIMTLFYRYMPEVI
QGGHLYIATPPLYKCSKGKISEYCYTDEARQAFIQKYGEGNEQGIHTQRYKGLGEMNPEQ
LWETTMNPETRILKQVNIENAAEADYIFSMLMGDDVGPRREFIEKNATYANIDA
```

I can easily remove the 'Sbjct' line and the numbers with sed commands but I don't know how to exempt the id line (k141_112817...) from the sed commands. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: `sed -n  -r '1p; s/([^ ]+)\s+([^ ]+)\s+(.{61}) .*/\3/gp' inputfile` should help

Comment: Simply match lines you need to process, and replace a whole line with the selected character range within the line. Something like this:

`sed -e 's/Sbjct[[:space:]][[:space:]]*[0-9][0-9]*[[:space:]][[:space:]]*\([^[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]].*/\1/' input`

Comment: The above also works, but I think using the awk commands (below) are a simpler way to accomplish this. Thank you for your input though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think`sed` is the wrong tool, since it appears that you want:

```
awk '/^Sbjct/{$0 = $3}1' input-file
```

Comment: Yep, you were absolutely right, this worked perfectly and I think its much less convoluted than sed commands. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -E '/^>/n;s/\S+\s*//4;s///2;s///1' file
```

GNU sed with `-E` to allow extended regex

- `/^>/n` to preserve the line beginning with `>` (Using `n` command)
- `s/\S+\s*//4` to remove the 4th word.  `\S` is non-whitespace
- `s///2` to remove the 2nd word  (The empty match in the substitution will use the previous match)
- `s///1` to remove the 1st word

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^Sbjct/s/.* .* (\S+) .*/\1/' file
```

When a line starting `Sbjct` is encountered, remove the first two fields and last (and the intervening spaces).

This is sed solvable but in this case I agree with William Pursell and would use Awk.